# Check isDaylightSavingTime for

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nscalendar

The [Using Time Zones Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html)
shows how to check if daylight saving time (DST) is in action for the current date and how to get the next date when daylight saving time changes. With calls to:

```
isDaylightSavingTime
daylightSavingTimeOffset
nextDaylightSavingTime
```

E.g.

```
Bool isDST = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] isDaylightSavingTime];
```

But I need to find out if a **future date** is DST or not so that when users scroll to a distant and far off date, they can see my graph plotted with the time axis labelled correctly (GMT or BST).

The problem is that *isDayLightSavingTime* seems to take two parameters, one passed to it explicitly (NSTimeZone) and the other implicitly, namely the current system time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to call [`isDaylightSavingTimeForDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/isDaylightSavingTimeForDate%3a), passing in the relevant `NSDate`.

It's not that `isDaylightSavingTime` itself has two parameters - it's that it calls `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate` with the current date. From the [docs for `isDaylightSavingTime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/isDaylightSavingTime):

> This method invokes `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:` with the current date as the argument.

So just skip the "convenience" method and call `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate` specifying the date you want to check. (I'd give some sample code, but the chances of me getting Objective C syntax correct are very slim...)

Comment: Thanks Jon. So I created a NSDateComponents object from my NSDate plus the offset. Then gave it my current system [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] then used in "if ([[components timeZone]  isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:date] == YES) "   Must admit I hadn't spotted the isDaylightSavingTimeForDate API call.

Comment: @NickT: Which offset do you mean? I'm not an iOS developer, but I'd expect `NSDate` to represent a point in time, so you shouldn't need to add an offset. It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but does the answer give you everything you need?

Comment: The offset is a number of days offset from now. And yes this is the answer I need. Thanks again.